# Jquery on event not working for Dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, onclick, tags, jquery-click-event

```
$(".spanCont:first .collection_shop").on("click",function(){
            var current_item = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/abc.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {collection_id: current_item.attr("value")},
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    current_item.replaceWith("<div id='temp_div'></div>");
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                $(".spanCont:first .span-2, .spanCont:first input").remove();
                $("#temp_div").replaceWith(data);
            });
        });
```

This code should work for all static and dynamic click of elements with class .collection_shop but its only working for static elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click",".spanCont:first .collection_shop",function(){
   //some operation
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for dynamic  elements

Answer (score 2):

You need other (delgation) version of on() for dynamic elements. Delegate event to static parent of the dynamically elements or you can use document / body etc.

```
$(document).on("click", ".spanCont:first .collection_shop", function(){
    var current_item = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/abc.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {collection_id: current_item.attr("value")},
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            current_item.replaceWith("<div id='temp_div'></div>");
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        $(".spanCont:first .span-2, .spanCont:first input").remove();
        $("#temp_div").replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

You have

```
$(".spanCont:first .collection_shop").on("click",function(){
```

You need, for event delegation

```
$("static-parent-selector").on("click", .spanCont:first .collection_shop, function(){
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on("click",".spanCont:first .collection_shop",function(){
//code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

like this

```
$(document).on("click",".spanCont:first .collection_shop",function(){
   // code here
});
```

or

```
$('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').on('click','.spanCont:first .collection_shop',function(){
   // code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach,  *a little kinder to your ui than setting event delegation from the root 'document'*

Split the AJAX from the listener to it's own function and create a listener function that 're listens' after the DOM has been updated by the code in the ajax call.

It's good to separate anyway ( say in the future you want to trigger the ajax request from something else)

```
function ajaxCall() {

  /* ... do the ajax call and return data   */
 .....done(function() { 

  /* update the DOM et al */

  /* reset the listener */
  listen();

 });
}

function listen() {
 $(".spanCont:first .collection_shop").off("click").on("click",function(){
   ajaxCall();
 });
}
/* start */
listen();
```

like - http://jsbin.com/foruyapi/1/edit

Comment: * if those `.collection_shop` elements are added dynamically - it would be worth giving the `:first` element it's own unique class too - to cut down on the selector syntax.